# iptables / firewall blocking traffic (even SSH) on my dedicated box

Tags: centos, iptables, firewall

Can someone please take a look at this iptables data and tell me what's wrong with it?

The paste 24h has been a nightmare, I couldn't even SSH to my server, and the only way I could manage to get the server back online was to use an KVM console and disable the  firewall (ie. `service iptables stop`)

The worst thing is: I have to re-run this command `service iptables stop` every like 15-30 minutes to get the server back online, this is crazy!

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.3.5 on Sun Dec  8 21:56:04 2013
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
:ALLOWIN - [0:0]
:ALLOWOUT - [0:0]
:INVALID - [0:0]
:INVDROP - [0:0]
:LOCALINPUT - [0:0]
:LOCALOUTPUT - [0:0]
:LOGDROPIN - [0:0]
:LOGDROPOUT - [0:0]
:acctboth - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j acctboth 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -j LOCALINPUT 
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -j INVALID 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2077 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2078 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2082 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2083 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2086 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2087 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2095 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2096 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2382 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 26 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 30000:35000 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 12001:12009 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 9418 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8001 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8002 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 6379 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 119 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 2382 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 26 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 119 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -m limit --limit 1/sec -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -m limit --limit 1/sec -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i eth0 -j LOGDROPIN 
-A OUTPUT -j acctboth 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -j LOCALOUTPUT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -j INVALID 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 9418 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 37 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 43 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 113 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 873 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2087 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2089 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2703 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2382 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 26 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 30000:35000 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 12001 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 12009 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 6379 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 119 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 113 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 873 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 6277 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 2382 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 26 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 119 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -m limit --limit 1/sec -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -m limit --limit 1/sec -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -j LOGDROPOUT 
-A ALLOWIN -s 41.228.96.0/255.255.255.0 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT 
-A ALLOWIN -s 41.228.96.65 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT 
-A ALLOWIN -s 209.51.153.82 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT 
-A ALLOWOUT -d 41.228.96.0/255.255.255.0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT 
-A ALLOWOUT -d 41.228.96.65 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT 
-A ALLOWOUT -d 209.51.153.82 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT 
-A INVALID -m state --state INVALID -j INVDROP 
-A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j INVDROP 
-A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG -j INVDROP 
-A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN FIN,SYN -j INVDROP 
-A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j INVDROP 
-A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,RST FIN,RST -j INVDROP 
-A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,ACK FIN -j INVDROP 
-A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags PSH,ACK PSH -j INVDROP 
-A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags ACK,URG URG -j INVDROP 
-A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m state --state NEW -j INVDROP 
-A INVDROP -j DROP 
-A LOCALINPUT -i eth0 -j ALLOWIN 
-A LOCALOUTPUT -o eth0 -j ALLOWOUT 
-A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 68 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 111 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 111 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 113 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 113 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 135:139 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 135:139 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 445 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 445 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 513 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 513 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 520 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 520 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m limit --limit 30/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Firewall: *TCP_IN Blocked* " 
-A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m limit --limit 30/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Firewall: *UDP_IN Blocked* " 
-A LOGDROPIN -p icmp -m limit --limit 30/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Firewall: *ICMP_IN Blocked* " 
-A LOGDROPIN -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPOUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m limit --limit 30/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Firewall: *TCP_OUT Blocked* " --log-uid 
-A LOGDROPOUT -p udp -m limit --limit 30/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Firewall: *UDP_OUT Blocked* " --log-uid 
-A LOGDROPOUT -p icmp -m limit --limit 30/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Firewall: *ICMP_OUT Blocked* " --log-uid 
-A LOGDROPOUT -j DROP 
-A acctboth -s 111.11.11.146 -i ! lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 
-A acctboth -d 111.11.11.146 -i ! lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 
-A acctboth -s 111.11.11.146 -i ! lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 
-A acctboth -d 111.11.11.146 -i ! lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 25 
-A acctboth -s 111.11.11.146 -i ! lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 
-A acctboth -d 111.11.11.146 -i ! lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 110 
-A acctboth -s 111.11.11.146 -i ! lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -d 111.11.11.146 -i ! lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -s 111.11.11.146 -i ! lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -d 111.11.11.146 -i ! lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -s 111.11.11.146 -i ! lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -d 111.11.11.146 -i ! lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -s 111.11.11.146 -i ! lo 
-A acctboth -d 111.11.11.146 -i ! lo 
-A acctboth -s 111.11.11.160 -i ! lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 
-A acctboth -d 111.11.11.160 -i ! lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 
-A acctboth -s 111.11.11.160 -i ! lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 
-A acctboth -d 111.11.11.160 -i ! lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 443 
-A acctboth -s 111.11.11.160 -i ! lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 
-A acctboth -d 111.11.11.160 -i ! lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 25 
-A acctboth -s 111.11.11.160 -i ! lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 
-A acctboth -d 111.11.11.160 -i ! lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 110 
-A acctboth -s 111.11.11.160 -i ! lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -d 111.11.11.160 -i ! lo -p icmp 
-A acctboth -s 111.11.11.160 -i ! lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -d 111.11.11.160 -i ! lo -p tcp 
-A acctboth -s 111.11.11.160 -i ! lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -d 111.11.11.160 -i ! lo -p udp 
-A acctboth -s 111.11.11.160 -i ! lo 
-A acctboth -d 111.11.11.160 -i ! lo 
-A acctboth -i ! lo 
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Dec  8 21:56:04 2013
# Generated by iptables-save v1.3.5 on Sun Dec  8 21:56:04 2013
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [52:2991]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [131:10103]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [131:10103]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Dec  8 21:56:04 2013
# Generated by iptables-save v1.3.5 on Sun Dec  8 21:56:04 2013
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1314:156437]
:INPUT ACCEPT [1314:156437]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1741:1844557]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1741:1844557]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Dec  8 21:56:04 2013
```

The KVM console showed a [lot of errors like this](http://derp.co.uk/8f57c)

Clearly the errors are caused by these lines:

```
-A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m limit --limit 30/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Firewall: *TCP_IN Blocked* " 
-A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m limit --limit 30/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Firewall: *UDP_IN Blocked* " 
-A LOGDROPIN -p icmp -m limit --limit 30/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Firewall: *ICMP_IN Blocked* " 
-A LOGDROPIN -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPOUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m limit --limit 30/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Firewall: *TCP_OUT Blocked* " --log-uid 
-A LOGDROPOUT -p udp -m limit --limit 30/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Firewall: *UDP_OUT Blocked* " --log-uid 
-A LOGDROPOUT -p icmp -m limit --limit 30/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Firewall: *ICMP_OUT Blocked* " --log-uid 
-A LOGDROPOUT -j DROP
```

But I have absolutely no idea why this is happening and how to fix this!!!

PS. As you can tell, I'm a total newbie at this firewall rules thing.

I'm running **CentOS 6.4 + Apache 2.2.15**, **I'm not using cPanel anymore on this server.**

Comment: What did cPanel support tell you?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I disabled cPanel like a year ago (though I didn't do any cleanup). I edited my question to add that info

Comment: That's not really good enough. cPanel makes so many nonstandard changes to a server that the only reasonable way to get rid of it is to reinstall the server from scratch.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I **truly** wish I could, this server still does use some legacy software (can't upgrade right now, so I have to make sure the show continue running until I figure out some magic solution)

Comment: The firewall rules appears to be ok, something may be updating your firewall rules though. Could you list updated rules of when you have this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 things :

1. You should not put any rules before:

   -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
2. Your "INVALID" rule should not be there, and looks far too much convoluted, and likely to be buggy.

I suggest you limit it to only `-m state --state INVALID` and I strongly suggest **that you log the INVALID packets**.

There are also bugs in which netfilter will treat valid packets as invalid ( of course netfilter says that it is other vendors who are wrong ), especially when you are behind a load balancer / firewall, but at first you should simply remove the pseudo "invalid check", and if you believe they have any value you should put them after the --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED rule and log the packets you think are invalid.

The messages on the KVM console are perfectly normal according to your set of rules.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest eliminating the --limit records and see if it works.  If you have problems with denial-of-service attacks then you can try to figure out limits.  But my guess is you don't need them.